# Assign a list of items to a specific attributes from another list Linq

Tags: c#, list, linq

Let's say I have two lists, a list of `bookIds` and a list of `book`.

The list of `bookIds` looks like this:

```
var bookIds = new List<string>();
```

The list of `books` looks something like this:

```
var books = new List<Book>();

public class Book
{
     public string bookId;
     public string bookName;
}
```

I would like to use `Linq` and assign each id in the `bookIds` list to the `bookId` property of the list `book` at the same index. I want to avoid using for loop and was wondering if I could leverage Linq.

I could do something like this but I am not sure how to assign the entire bookIds list to one property of another list:

```
books.foreach(x => x.bookId = bookIds); // ==> this is wrong but you might get my idea
```

Comment: you want to select from books where their id is in bookid list?

Comment: I want to assign the bookId list to the books list's bookId property

Comment: if books already have id's there is no point assining again, if they don't how to know which book should have which bookid, and if the books have no bookid and no book name, it would be just creating new list of books with no names and just ids.

Comment: there must be a relation between these 2 lists to know which item of list1 should be assigned to which item of list2. this relation usually would be the id that in your case it is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update:

As [Theodor suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55486076/assign-a-list-of-items-to-a-specific-attributes-from-another-list-linq#comment97682371_55486131), `IndexOf` could affect the performance considerablly, specially if you have a large list. To avoid using `IndexOf`, you can create an `int` variable and increment it inside the `ForEach`:

```
int i = 0;
books.ForEach(x => x.bookId = bookIds[i++]);
```

### Original answer:

If you want to assign the first id in the `bookIds` list to the first book in the `books` list and the second id to the second book and so on, you can do something like this:<sup>*</sup>

```
books.ForEach(x => x.bookId = bookIds[books.IndexOf(x)]);
```

**Full example:**

```
var bookIds = new List<string>() { "1", "2" };
var books = new List<Book>()
    { new Book() { bookName = "Book1" },
      new Book() { bookName = "Book2"}
    };
books.ForEach(x => x.bookId = bookIds[books.IndexOf(x)]);

Console.WriteLine(books[0].bookName + " has id: " + books[0].bookId);
Console.WriteLine(books[1].bookName + " has id: " + books[1].bookId);
```

**Output:**

```
Book1 has id: 1
Book2 has id: 2
```

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Please be aware that this will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if `bookIds` has fewer elements than `books`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Follow up question, what if the `books` list is empty? how do I assign the bookId list to an empty book list?

Comment: @superninja Do you mean create a new `Book` for each Id in the `bookIds` list?

Comment: yes, you are right. Assigning the bookIds list to an empty `Book` list

Comment: @superninja `books = bookIds.Select(x => new Book() { bookId = x }).ToList();`.

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed your code is inefficient. For every element of the books list you are making a linear search inside the same list (O(n²) complexity).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Added a solution that doesn't use `IndexOf`. Please see the update.

Comment: It would be more efficient to use the [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) method, but I don't want to propose it as a solution because it is quite obvious that OP's architecture has bigger problems that need to be addressed first.
Btw your updated solution is efficient, but not very robust. :-)